# Retiring data/ data rollover in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

ES newbie here, trying to figure out exactly how to impose a document TTL or basic data cleanup for holding only one day of data.

We are currently parsing about 80GB a day and its filling up our disk space, elastic.co KB is not proving to be useful. Any help or insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you have **multiple daily indices**, you can use the handy [curator tool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html), which allows you to manage your indices.

For instance, in order to delete all indices that are older than one day, you'd run curator like this:

```
curator delete indices --older-than 1 --time-unit days
```

If you have a **single index** and you'd like to delete data that is older than one day, you can use the [delete by query plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.3/plugins-delete-by-query.html) and delete data whose timestamp is older than 1 day:

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/your_index/_query -d '{
   "query": {
      "range": {
         "timestamp_field": {
            "lt": "now-1d"
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

In a situation like yours I would just allocate a new index each day and then close/delete them after rolling over a to a new one, much the same as @Val suggested using an external tool.

However, I did notice in the docs that the Index and Bulk operations still support the [TTL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-ttl) parameter. You might find that useful in this case, though there is a deprecation warning and I still think the more robust solution if you have the disk space is to rotate indices.